# Postback automáticos y suspensión/hibernación de equipo generan error de navegador

Tags: asp.net

Muy buenas tardes,
Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar con el siguiente problema que se me está presentando:

Tengo una página web en `ASP.NET 2.0` que posee un temporizador `asp:Timer` que tras cierto intervalo de tiempo efectúa un Postback en la página principal para recargar su contenido. Este comportamiento funciona realmente bien durante el transcurso del ciclo de vida de la página. Sin embargo, cuando efectúo una suspensión/hibernación del equipo por varios minutos (probé con 10-15 minutos), al visualizar nuevamente la página, veo que esta ha "muerto" por distintos motivos (señalados como "*ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED*" o "*ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED*" en Chrome, y parecidos en Firefox), deteniendo de manera drástica su funcionamiento, no permitiéndome continuar con las tareas normales que esta realiza, ni siquiera pudiendo controlar el error.

¿Qué opciones existen para que ante esta situación, la página no "muera" en su totalidad y pueda seguir funcionando con normalidad?
Adjunto una imagen de como se ve la página tras dicho problema.[image: Error tras recuperación de suspensión/hibernación]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: No creo que el Timer de ASP funcione de esa manera (es decir, que siga funcionando cuando el equipo está en hibernación). Por favor añade información sobre cómo hiciste ese Timer y cuál es la función (o funciones) de ese Timer.

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Arias Olave, estoy de acuerdo con que no funcione en suspensión/hibernación, el problema es que al recuperarse el equipo, la página pasa al estado presentado. Mi objetivo es que la página vuelva a funcionar cuando el equipo se recupere sin interacción por parte del usuario. De hecho, también ocurre con un "setInterval" cualquiera que tenga un postback tras cierto intervalo de tiempo.